# Computing the following limit

Tags: limits

I am required to compute this result in order to figure out another result. So I'm trying to show that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1-e^{-(\ln(n)+x)})^n = e^{-e^{-x}}$$

I'm hestiant to use the L'hopital rule since we have a power to the $n$ there. Maybe I will need to take the natural logarithm on both sides to reduce this down further. I'm out of ideas anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e^{-(\ln n + x)} = e^{-\ln n}e^{-x} = \dfrac{1}{n}e^{-x}$, the limit becomes $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\dfrac{e^{-x}}{n}\right)^n$.

Now, apply the definition $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{y}{n}\right)^n = e^y$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not quite sure where the minus sign went when you applied the definition.

Comment: $1-\frac{y}{n}=1+\frac{-y}{n}$. @Fred21Jones

Comment: Thanks forgot it was $e^{-e^{-x}}$. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Taking $\ln$ we have:
$n\ln\left(1-e^{-(\ln n + x)}\right)= e^{-x}\dfrac{\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}e^{-x}\right)}{e^{-x}\frac{1}{n}}\to -e^{-x}\to L = e^{-e^{-x}}$

Comment: Thanks for the alternative with logs!